# Snap not allowing me to remove or refresh anything

Tags: snap

I installed my dev tools via snap, big updates came out for most of them recently (Jetbrains), biggest being Android studio. But no matter what I do I can't remove or update any of my applications installed via snap.

When I try to remove the snap, I get the following error message:

```
error: snap "android-studio" has "auto-refresh" change in progress
```

I tried disabling "auto-refresh" with a bunch of other recommendations from other questions and threads.

I would like to specify *when* I want to update. Is there any way to update snaps like regular APT packages?

When I run "snap refresh", I get the following error:

```
error: change finished in status "Hold" with no error message
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change schedule for automatic updates

[Managing updates | Snapcraft documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date)

Comment: This does not word on fedora, brings up 'unknown flag hold'

Answer (score 25):

This was the top search item for the topic as I was trying to remove a snap whilst it was "auto-refreshing".  The better answer in that it allows you to **stop** the refresh and take action is covered in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029117/unable-to-install-package-snap-package-has-install-snap-change-in-pro).

In effect:

```
# Check for snap changes
sudo snap changes

# This will list something like
ID         Status   Spawn                  Ready   Summary
<number>   Doing    today at 10:58 CEST    -       Auto-refresh snap <snap_program>

# Note the ID for the refresh and abort it
sudo snap abort <number>

# You must check changes until it has been actioned
sudo snap changes

# This will now list something like
ID         Status   Spawn                  Ready   Summary
<number>   Error    today at 10:58 CEST    -       Auto-refresh snap <snap_program>

# The take remedial action, in my case remove
sudo snap remove <snap_program>
```

Tested with `microk8s` on Ubuntu 18.04 and `chromium` on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to forcibly remove a snap when a refresh is in process.

Once the refresh is finished, you can speed up the snap removal by skipping the backup using `--purge`. Normally, when a snap is removed, the data of that snap is backed up. This backup can take some time.

```
snap remove --purge android-studio
```

Note that this command will **remove all data** from that snap.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to the previous version (removing changes done by the update) first will solve this problem, after which allow you to also delete the snap package with no errors:

```
[rodolfo@fedora ~]$ sudo snap revert discord 
discord reverted to 0.0.13

[rodolfo@fedora ~]$ sudo snap remove discord 
discord removed
```

Answer (score 0):

Check snap changes then note down the ID

```
sudo snap changes                                          10 ↵  
ID   Status  Spawn                   Ready                   Summary
746  Done    yesterday at 01:28 IST  yesterday at 01:30 IST  Pre-download "android-studio" for auto-refresh
747  Done    yesterday at 12:24 IST  yesterday at 12:26 IST  Pre-download "android-studio" for auto-refresh
748  Done    yesterday at 22:29 IST  today at 07:25 IST      Pre-download "android-studio" for auto-refresh
749  Done    today at 07:41 IST      today at 07:42 IST      Pre-download "android-studio" for auto-refresh
750  Error   today at 09:57 IST      today at 09:59 IST      Auto-refresh snap "android-studio"
751  Doing   today at 10:00 IST      -                       Auto-refresh snap "android-studio"
```

Then run abort

```
sudo snap abort 751
```

Wait for a few min then refresh/remove manually

```
 sudo snap refresh android-studio
```

Answer (score -3):

You can add the parameter "now" to the end of your command, it will ignore the "auto-refresh".

example:

```
sudo snap remove android-studio now
```

Comment: This command tries to remove the snaps named `android-studio` and `now`. It will not actually force the removal.

Answer (score -4):

The way it worked for me was the parameter `force` instead of `now`

```
sudo snap remove android-studio force
```

Comment: This command tries to remove the snaps named `android-studio` and `force`. It will not actually force the removal.