# Completely uninstall Notepad ++ snap package in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, snap

I was trying to install the Notepad++ snap package in Ubuntu 18.04 by using `sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus`, but unfortunately I closed the terminal while the installation was still not finished. Now I can see the icon of Notepad++, but I can't run it, so I'm trying to remove it with the following commands:

```
sudo snap abort --last auto-refresh
sudo snap disable notepad-plus-plus
sudo snap remove notepad-plus-plus
```

and the terminal outputs the following results:

```
ch@ch-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo snap abort --last auto-refresh
[sudo] password for ch:
error: cannot abort change 6 with nothing pending
ch@ch-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo snap disable notepad-plus-plus
error: snap "notepad-plus-plus" has "install-snap" change in progress
ch@ch-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo snap remove notepad-plus-plus
error: snap "notepad-plus-plus" has "install-snap" change in progress
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install "<PACKAGE>": snap "<PACKAGE>" has "install-snap" change in progress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029117/unable-to-install-package-snap-package-has-install-snap-change-in-pro)

Comment: Reboot and try again. Always works for me. It happens to me when I try to install sometimes too. You can have only 1 snap process in progress at a time. Also you will need to use code `sudo snap purge notepad-plus-plus` if you want to completely remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the parameter "now" to the end of your command, it will ignore the "auto-refresh".

example:

```
sudo snap remove notepad-plus-plus now
```