# I get snap error when i try to installl chromium-browser

Tags: apt, chromium, snap

When i type this:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium-browser
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 48.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 164 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 chromium-browser amd64 80.0.3987.163-0ubuntu1 [48.3 kB]
Fetched 48.3 kB in 6s (8,267 B/s)           
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package chromium-browser.
(Reading database ... 178512 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chromium-browser_80.0.3987.163-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the chromium snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the chromium snap
error: snap "chromium" has "install-snap" change in progress
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_80.0.3987.163-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new chromium-browser package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_80.0.3987.163-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1029117/590937

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm thinking that you have something in background that is preventing that you install the package

run `$ snap changes`

you will get something similar to this, you should search on any doing/ongoing process so you can abort it

```
ID Estate Generated Ready Description
10 Doing  when            installing snap "chromium"
```

Now you will grab that Doing process ID and you just type this, 10 is my process you will get a different one.
With this command, you will abort the process so you can generate a new one hopefully without any trouble

```
$ sudo snap abort 10
```