# Unable to install snap package(s)

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, snap

Pre-requisite:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (minimal installation) on a VirtualBox 6.1

I was trying to install VS Code through Snap:

```
$ snap install code --classic
error: cannot install "code": Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh:
   x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Then I tried PyCharm CE also, same error:

```
$ snap install pycharm-community --classic
error: cannot install "pycharm-community": Post
   https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: x509: certificate signed by
   unknown authority
```

Comment: Are you using a school or corporate network that uses a self-signed certificate? Is your Core snap properly refreshed?  (The Core snap holds the current certificate chains).

Comment: @user535733, yes I am trying on my official Laptop.

Comment: is the system date of your computer +- correct ?

Comment: @Koen, yes. It gets updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: [askubuntu.com/questions/1029117](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029117/unable-to-install-package-snap-package-has-install-snap-change-in-pro)

> Snap is probably still working on something in the background (or at least it thinks so). Open a terminal and run snap changes so see a list of ongoing changes.

```
$ snap changes

...
8  Doing   2018-04-28T10:40:11Z  -  Install "foo" snap
...
```

You can abort ongoing "Do" or "Doing" change(s):

```
sudo snap abort 8
```

Original answer by [fnkr](https://askubuntu.com/users/26187/fnkr)