# I get this prompt whenever I install a software from the center

Tags: software-installation, games

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPenv.png)

What should I do to fix this?
I tried reinstalling software-center and ubuntu-software
I tried sudo apt-get update and upgrade

Comment: Hello. Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029117/unable-to-install-package-snap-package-has-install-snap-change-in-pro).

Comment: It looks to me like another `snap install` process is running. Try to kill that process from a command prompt, or reboot.