# store problem in Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: ubuntu-store

I am trying to install programs but it keeps saying this please help:  (Ubuntu 22.04.2)

```
Unable to install "OBS Studio": status-code=409 kind-snap-change-conflict message=snap "obs- studio" has "install-snap" change in progress
```

Comment: i updated to 22.04.2 LTS the store is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install "<PACKAGE>": snap "<PACKAGE>" has "install-snap" change in progress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029117/unable-to-install-package-snap-package-has-install-snap-change-in-pro)